# How can I apply same image texture at different angles?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to apply the same texture image to parts of the top face of a mesh cube at different angles.
Refer to image below which shows the 'decking' around the building with planking at different angles. I have added red arrows where the change of direction of the planking is.
I guess I need to 'break up' the top face into separate faces and then apply the texture image to each face but what is the best method to break a single face into multiple faces?
Note how the planks in front of the doorway are diagonal to the sides and the planks next to those are parallel to the sides.

[added later]
I tried adding loop cuts and moving them appropriately but then could not select individual faces to add material.

Here is my Blender file with cuts added but I cannot select the individual faces on the top surface to add material.

[image]

[image]

[image added later to demonstrate problem - see bottom of thread]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean after adding loop cuts you could not select individual faces to add material? I downloaded your file, I can select faces. Assigning materials to them would be easier if there were materials on the object, but after I added them I could assign them to individual faces so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: As the problem was with selecting faces to apply a material not the material I didn't think uploading the material was necessary. HURRAH I have just noticed that for those faces which do not get highlited when I click on them (and the face on the bottom gets highlited instead)    if I then double click it then selects the face on the TOP. I have NEVER needed to double click to select before!        Well that is news to me (need to double click to select) .      If only someone before you had suggested that I double click to select (when the first click selected the face on the bottom).

Comment: You could simply disable _X-Ray_ if you want to work on faces at the top. Without _X-Ray_ the bottom faces will not be visible or selectable through the top faces. Click the button or hit Alt+Z to toggle _X-Ray_ mode on and off.

Comment: That (You could simply disable X-Ray if you want to work on faces at the top) is a great suggestion and perhaps a trap for the unwary like me. And also something no one else picked up on (from my Blender file)

Comment: No, no one picked that up because it is not wrong to model in _X-Ray_ if you knew what it does. Sorry, no offense - but you should really try to learn the basic functions, options and modes of how to use the viewport and the basic tools. You are sometimes asking for slightly advanced stuff like unwrapping etc. and it would make it much easier to help you with more complex problems if you knew the basics.

Comment: I never knew that and up till now - I thought it was only use to view all vertices, faces and edges. I only ever used it to delete vertices including those not seen (when 'lassoing' a section. There are so many different aspects of many things such as viewports not to mention the different 'forms' of some tools such as extrude which would only be learned by trying each one OR by reading the entire Blender manual and trying to remember everything which is read AND knowing where each could be used. Even if I read the entire manual I would not remember half of it as a lot would go 'over my head'.

Comment: ...but at least you know that _X-Ray_ mode can be used to select vertices that are not seen, that's a start ;) And when selecting faces - when you click in an area where top and bottom faces are visible, it always selects the face which center dot is closest to the mouse cursor, no matter if it's at the top or the bottom. Usually it always selects the closest, no matter if edge or vertex. It just becomes tricky if two or more lie in the exact or nearly same location (either in 3D or 2D, if you are maybe looking top down on something for example).

Answer (score 0):

Simple UV mapping is usually used to control how textures show up on a 3d model. UV mapping defines texture coordinates of a 3d model in 2d space. It's a way to unfold the 3d surface of a model to 2d image texture space. It is sort of basic principle in 3d graphics and you can find all the information about it online. It's really easy to find plenty of good tutorials about it online.

See the documentation on UV tools in Blender: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv.html

Blender.org offers plenty of good resources for getting started: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I have been successfully 'unwrapping' texture images for some time by adding the texture image material, select edit mode, ctrl E and select mark seams then press u twice then select Uv Editing  also  in edit mode using face select and then click on the face required and applying an image texture but for this NOTHING works. Obviously it has something to do with the fact that I did some loop cuts which I have never done before but I have no idea why I can't unwrap.  Maybe the only method is to create my decking with 9 separate mesh cubes?

Comment: [added later] Or (as I just found out by experimenting) select each separate cube formed by loop cut and then press p and select by selection to form separate mesh cubes and then apply material to each separate mesh cube. Surely that is not the best way?

Comment: It definitely works. One material is enough if it is one material you want to create. Make sure you make separate UV islands for parts you wish to be different and rotate the UVs as needed. I think watching a few tutorials could be helpful.

Comment: I am only wanting to use one material for each face created by loop cuts (but rotating it for different UV islands).  I cannot find a tutorial which specifically explains how to add a single material to each face created with loop cuts. I have reworked and reworked my model starting with a mesh cube which I CAN apply a material to but once I add loop cuts if won't work.   Please advise a suitable tutorial to watch as I cannot find any and/or open my blender file and see if you can apply a SINGLE material to each SEPARATE face created by the loop cuts.

Comment: This is very basic stuff and I am not sure what exactly the problem is. I mean, it's really hard to understand how you attempt to do it and where it fails. I strongly recommend watching the basics tutorials from blender.org - they will sort all problems out. Example you provide in the question could be done [like this](https://imgur.com/a/6NP8WHD). My seems are marked red there. They are on the corners and the diagonal line.

Comment: I have added an image of the edit screen (to initial question top of thread) showing all loop cuts. I have selected every separate area of the top face and you will see that it only displays 4 of those areas. THAT I think is the problem I face (not a pun) and I have NO idea why that is. No matter what I do I cannot select the other areas to apply material to. If I rotate the entire mesh 180 degrees I can see the face IS selected only it is on the bottom. If you load the blender file you will seen what I mean.  I have NO idea how that can happen but will redo the entire mesh cube again.

Comment: [added later] Well I removed the 'rogue' mesh and added a new one and added loop cuts. The SAME thing happens. When I select some of the rectangles formed by the loop cuts the face BENEATH is selected. Could it be that I have the building positioned on that mesh cube. I have NO problems when I add a mesh cube and do loop cuts with no other mesh objects positioned. The reason why I have the building placed on the mesh cube is to position the loop cuts using the corners of the building.

Comment: It seems to definitely be affected by have another mesh intersecting with the mesh cube which has the loops cuts added. If I start with a SINGLE mesh cube and add loop cuts I can select ALL the areas on the top face created with the loops cuts. If I add an 8 sided cylinder to represent the octagonal shaped building so that I can align the loops cuts with the corners then remove the 8 sided cylinder then I CANNOT select some of the areas on the top face.   What is the answer?  How can I set the position of the loop cuts to align with the corners?

Answer (score 0):

Start by selecting the bottom 8 edges of the building and making a copy of them with **Shft** **D**. Next make these new edges a separate object, **P** > **Selection**.

In object mode hide the building, H key.

Select the new octagon edge object and tab into edit mode. In top orthographic view select all of the octagon and extrude out to create the width of the planking. With a combination of individual vertex extruding and snapping add the corners to create the square shape and then fill in any missing faces.

Next add seams as shown in the image below and then UV unwrap.

Edit the resulting UV islands so that similar islands are stacked one above the other, see image below and rotate, position and scale UV islands to align with texture image.
[image]

Alternative vertex alignment :
[image]

To give the planking thickness you would need to extrude the outer edges of the square down a little before the marking ofseams and unwrapping.

Comment: Thanks 3fingeredfrog.  I had replied before but since then Gordon has sent a reply (see top of thread) and after that with experimenting on my part I discovered that if I double clicked on a face (created with the loop cuts) which would only select the face on the bottom, it would then select the TOP face. So I don't need to use your suggestion but do THANK YOU very much for taking the time to do that for me. As mentioned to Gordon in my reply to him, I have NEVER needed to double click on a face before and it was completely NEW to me. Thanks again.